# How to upload a file to Wordpress database from a custom Gutenberg block?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, file-upload, gutenberg-blocks

I am looking to create a custom Gutenberg block with javascript that has an input that will let you upload a file of any format, and then store it in the database so I can show it on the front-end inside html a tag to be downloaded.

Here is the code inside my index.js inside my block folder (I know it is not good code. it is just for demo purposes)

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockType('sab/upload-block', {
  title: 'Upload Block',
  icon: 'lightbulb',
  category: 'common',
  attributes: {
    url: 'string', default: '',
  },
  description: 'Add downloadable files to your post.',
  example: { attributes: {}},
  edit: function (props) {

    function fileDecoder(identifier) {    
      const input = document.querySelector(`#${identifier}`);
      const fReader = new FileReader();
      fReader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      fReader.onloadend = function(event) {
        setAttribute({url: event.target.result})
      }
    }

    return (
      <>
        <label>Upload a file</label>
        <input id='upload-file' type="file" onChange={() => props.fileDecoder('upload-file')} />
      </>
    )
  },
  save: function () {
    return null
  }
 })
```

And here is the code inside my index.php

```
<?php

/*
  Plugin Name: Upload Block
  Description: Add downloadable files to your post.
  Version: 1.0
  Author: XYZ
*/

if( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

// file inside my inc folder that creates the markup
require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'inc/generateUploadBlockHTML.php';

class UploadBlock {
  function __construct() {
    add_action('init', array($this, 'assets'));
  }

  function assets() {
    register_block_type(__DIR__, array(
      'render_callback' => array($this, 'theHTML')
    ));
  }

  function theHTML($attributes) {
    if (isset($attributes)) {

      // IDEALLY UPLOAD THE FILE HERE SO I CAN JUST USE IT ELSEWHERE, BUT I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO DO IT

      return <a href="$attributes['data']['url]" download="file">
    } else {
      return NULL;
    }
  }
}

$uploadBlock = new UploadBlock();
```

I tried using just javascript to achieve this but I believe i need to upload the file on Wordpress database so I can use it in my other templates.